# Ethernet dongle not working on a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon

Tags: hardware, ethernet

I have recently bought a Thinkpad X1 Carbon, installed Ubuntu 12.10 and everything I need works like a charm - except for the Ethernet USB dongle. Searching Google hasn't brought up any solutions or even suggestions, so I'm wondering if I'm the only one experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the output of `lsusb`, I did some more research and found a well documented solution, modifying an existing asix driver to support the Lenovo dongle:

[Case of the Broken Linux Driver (Lenovo USB 2.0 Ethernet 10/100 dongle)](https://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2012/10/22/case-of-the-broken-linux-driver-lenovo-usb-2-0-ethernet-10100-dongle/)

After compiling and installing the driver, the dongle now works immediately.

Comment: Please provide the output of `lsusb` by editing your original question, so that others can benefit from your research and know if this solution will apply to them.